# Rellenar datos faltantes en Dataframe (PANDAS) + (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 2 dataframes independientes (a,b) necesito crear un nuevo dataframe (c) a partir de (a, b), que muestre las siguientes columnas en el nuevo dataframe:

Dataframe (a) = ("usuario", "Codigo_Producto", "Precio")
Dataframe (b) = ("valoración_producto)
NuevoDataframe (c) = ("usuario", "Codigo_Producto", "Precio", "valoracion_producto")

El problema es que despues de juntar los dataframes (a + b), necesito que los datos de (valoracion_producto) aparezcan para cada uno de los productos, en el nuevo dataframe, gracias de antemano a los que contesteis.

> DataFrame (a)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

user1 = ["1", "R2055", "7500"]
user2 = ["2", "R2053", "8500"]
user3 = ["3", "R2055", "4500"]
user4 = ["4", "R2051", "6500"]
user5 = ["5", "R2057", "1500"]
user6 = ["6", "R2058", "3500"]
user7 = ["7", "R2056", "5500"]
user8 = ["8", "R2056", "8500"]
user9 = ["9", "R2052", "5500"]
user10 = ["10", "R2054", "9500"]
user11 = ["11", "R2057", "8500"]
user12 = ["12", "R2055", "7500"]

lista = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10, user11, user12]

df_product = pd.DataFrame(lista,
                         columns = ["Usuario", "Codigo_producto", "Precio"])
df_product
```

> DataFrame (b)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arg1 = ["R2053", "1 de 5"]
arg2 = ["R2051", "2 de 5"]
arg3 = ["R2056", "5 de 5"]
arg4 = ["R2057", "3 de 5"]
arg5 = ["R2054", "4 de 5"]
arg6 = ["R2055", "2 de 5"]
arg7 = ["R2052", "3 de 5"]
arg8 = ["R2058", "1 de 5"]

lista1 = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8]

df_rrss = pd.DataFrame(lista1,
                      columns = ["Producto", "Valoración_producto"])
```

> Resultado Esperado

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

user1 = ["1", "R2055", "7500", "2 de 5"]
user2 = ["2", "R2053", "8500", "1 de 5"]
user3 = ["3", "R2055", "4500", "2 de 5"]
user4 = ["4", "R2051", "6500", "2 de 5"]
user5 = ["5", "R2057", "1500", "3 de 5"]
user6 = ["6", "R2058", "3500", "1 de 5"]
user7 = ["7", "R2056", "5500", "5 de 5"]
user8 = ["8", "R2056", "8500", "5 de 5"]
user9 = ["9", "R2052", "5500", "3 de 5"]
user10 = ["10", "R2054", "9500", "4 de 5"]
user11 = ["11", "R2057", "8500", "3 de 5"]
user12 = ["12", "R2055", "7500", "2 de 5"]

lista = [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10, user11, user12]

df_product = pd.DataFrame(lista,
                         columns = ["Usuario", "Codigo_producto", "Precio", "Valoración_producto"])


df_product
```

[DataFrame (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8hBa.png)

[DataFrame (b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnog3.png)

[Resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIwq.png)

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how="inner")`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Cristian, pero no me funciona tu solución, ademas de (.merge), probe también con (.concat) y me sigue dando el mismo problema, me junta los 2 dataframes, pero no me da el resultado "valoración_producto" para cada uno de los elementos contenido en la columna "Codigo_producto" que es el problema que tengo.

Comment: mmm.. pues tendras que especificar en base a que columna quieres que se una, pero creo que tendrás problemas por los nombres, espera hago una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres podemos usar el método `merge` de pandas, con el cual podemos unir o combinar 2 o más *DataFrames*, donde indicaremos el *lado derecho* y el *lado izquierdo*. Dado que quieres unir en base a una columna en específico tendremos que usar el atributo `on` el cual indica en base a que hará el `merge`, pero como tus *DataFrames* tiene distintos valores tenemos que especificar ambas columnas.

```py
df_product = pd.merge(left=df_product, right=df_rrss, left_on="Codigo_producto", right_on="Producto", how="inner")
print(df_product)
```

**resultado**

|  | Usuario | Codigo_producto | Precio | Producto | Valoración_producto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | R2055 | 7500 | R2055 | 2 de 5 |
| 1 | 3 | R2055 | 4500 | R2055 | 2 de 5 |
| 2 | 12 | R2055 | 7500 | R2055 | 2 de 5 |
| 3 | 2 | R2053 | 8500 | R2053 | 1 de 5 |
| 4 | 4 | R2051 | 6500 | R2051 | 2 de 5 |
| 5 | 5 | R2057 | 1500 | R2057 | 3 de 5 |
| 6 | 11 | R2057 | 8500 | R2057 | 3 de 5 |
| 7 | 6 | R2058 | 3500 | R2058 | 1 de 5 |
| 8 | 7 | R2056 | 5500 | R2056 | 5 de 5 |
| 9 | 8 | R2056 | 8500 | R2056 | 5 de 5 |
| 10 | 9 | R2052 | 5500 | R2052 | 3 de 5 |
| 11 | 10 | R2054 | 9500 | R2054 | 4 de 5 |

Pero como solo te quieres quedar con la columna `Codigo_producto` tendremos que eliminar la otra y eso lo hacemos con el método `drop()`

```
df_product = df_product.drop(["Producto"], axis=1)
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, pero en el archivo de excel que utilizo tiene 500.000 filas, y me devuelve 1 dataframe con solo 300.000 y algo filas, las otras 200.000 no se que pasa con ellas, aun así me ha ayudado mucho tu respuesta. A ver si me ocurre alguna solución partiendo de tu respuesta.

Comment: puedes ordenar el DataFrame de forma ascendente según la columna `Usuario` y ver cuales falta y de ahí sacar una conclusión.

Comment: Probaré mañana a ver si consigo encontrar el problema con tu utlimo comentario,, aplicando lo que me has dicho, si averiguo algo lo pondre aquí para ayudar a más gente con el mismo problema.

Comment: ok, aunque también podrías editar mi respuesta añadiendo lo necesario, con gusto aceptaré tu edición ^_^

Comment: al final estaba bien el resultado de 300.000 y pico resultados que me aparecian, los otros 200.000 no apareceian porque simplemente no existia una valoracion de producto, para ese codigo de producto.